# Is there any way to make OCR work on smaller fonts? (except font teaching)

Tags: python

```
import easyocr
import pyautogui
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
from PIL import Image

def detect_numbers(region):
    reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])  # OCR modelini İngilizce olarak başlat

    while True:
        screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot(region=region)
        
        # PIL görüntüsüne dönüştür
        screenshot_pil = screenshot.convert('L')
        
        ocr_results = reader.readtext(np.array(screenshot_pil))
        timestamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
        screenshot_pil.save(f"C:/Users/furka/Pictures/Screenshotsscreenshot_{timestamp}.png")

        filtered_words = []
        for result in ocr_results:
            text = result[1]
            if text.isdigit() and len(text) == 8:  # Metnin sekiz basamaklı bir sayı olup olmadığını kontrol et
                filtered_words.append((text, result[0][0], result[0][1]))  # Sayıyı, sol üst köşe koordinatlarını ve boyutlarını filtrelenmiş kelimelere ekle
        
        if len(filtered_words) < 2:
            continue
        
        min_dist = float('inf')
        closest_pair = None
        for i in range(len(filtered_words) - 1):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(filtered_words)):
                dist = levenshtein_distance(filtered_words[i][0], filtered_words[j][0])
                if dist < min_dist:
                    min_dist = dist
                    closest_pair = (filtered_words[i], filtered_words[j])
        
        if min_dist > 2:
            continue
        
        winner = closest_pair[0] if closest_pair[0][1] < closest_pair[1][1] else closest_pair[1]
        print(f"Winner: {winner[0]}")
        
        # Ekrandaki diğer 8 haneli kodları da filtered_words listesine ekleyerek kazanan kelimenin tamamıyla karşılaştır
        for result in ocr_results:
            text = result[1]
            if text.isdigit() and len(text) == 8 and text != winner[0]:
                filtered_words.append((text, result[0][0], result[0][1]))
        
        # Kazanan kelimenin sol üst köşesine tıkla
        x, y = winner[1][0], winner[1][1]  # winner[1] ve winner[2] yerine winner[1][0] ve winner[1][1] kullanılmalı
        click_x = region[0] + x
        click_y = region[1] + y
        pyautogui.click(click_x, click_y)  # Kazananın sol üst köşesine tıkla
        
        time.sleep(1)

def levenshtein_distance(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) < len(s2):
        return levenshtein_distance(s2, s1)

    if len(s2) == 0:
        return len(s1)

    previous_row = range(len(s2) + 1)
    for i, c1 in enumerate(s1):
        current_row = [i + 1]
        for j, c2 in enumerate(s2):
            insertions = previous_row[j + 1] + 1
            deletions = current_row[j] + 1
            substitutions = previous_row[j] + (c1 != c2)
            current_row.append(min(insertions, deletions, substitutions))
        previous_row = current_row

    return previous_row[-1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Tarama yapılacak bölgenin koordinatlarını burada belirtin (sol, üst, genişlik, yükseklik)
    region = (704, 301, 399, 499)
    detect_numbers(region)
```

I tried converting the image to RGB - L before and tried to find out which one would work better, I also tried tesseract OCR, although it is a larger library, easyOCR works more stable in my process (I don't know why). Even though I made a few preliminary changes to the captured screenshot (enlarging the image by 400% - using a gray filter - contrast settings), I saw that it still did not work in small fonts. Finally, I selected a region and wanted it to scan only there. It is more stable than scanning the entire screen, but I still haven't solved the problem of detecting small fonts.